# Mixing configuration objects and Ext.create defined objects creates unclickable panel

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

If I have an application which contains panels created with Ext.create, and *those* panels have items which are created with *both* Ext.create and configuration objects, I get a panel whose interface is completely unclickable and doesn't respond to any interaction.

I've create [a sample JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rmj9a/1/) which illustrates the issue. Click the "TEST" button to see an example of this failure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do component creation at class definition time. That is, using `Ext.create` directly inside config object of `Ext.define`:

```
Ext.define('App.views.Panel1', {
    id:'panel1',
    extend:'Ext.Panel',
    config:{
        title: 'test',
        layout:'card',
        items:[
            {
                items:[
                    {
                        xtype: 'button',
                        text: 'TEST',
                        handler:function(){
                            Ext.getCmp('panel1').setActiveItem(Ext.getCmp('panel2'));
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            // not good
            Ext.create('App.views.Panel2', {id:'panel2'})
        ]
    }
});
```

Even if this would work, it would result in all instances of Panel1 sharing one Panel2 instance.

Instead you should do your component creation at initialization time:

```
Ext.define('App.views.Panel1', {
    id:'panel1',
    extend:'Ext.Panel',
    config:{
        title: 'test',
        layout:'card',
        items:[
            {
                items:[
                    {
                        xtype: 'button',
                        text: 'TEST',
                        handler:function(){
                            Ext.getCmp('panel1').setActiveItem(Ext.getCmp('panel2'));
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },

    initialize: function() {
        this.add(Ext.create('App.views.Panel2', {id:'panel2'}));
        this.callParent();
    }
});
```

The `initialize` method is a good place to do any kind of extra work you want to do every time you create an instance of your component class. `callParent` is there because we override `initialize` of a parent class which might have some of its own logic in there which we want to keep.

Comment: To expand on this, Ext.create *cannot* be used before Ext.application.

Comment: No such restriction. You can create a sencha-touch app without using Ext.application at all. Simply use Ext.create() and set fullscreen:true on the component you are creating.